# Xcode 6 stops working

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm using the latest version of Xcode 6.

When I click "images.xcassets" folder Xcode stops.

I've reinstalled my Xcode but Xcode still freezes.

What should I do?

Comment: if you are positive that you have installed it good, then you need to file a bug at apple. I have never heard of this happening

Comment: I deeply empathize with you, my friend. Try creating a fresh project and see if this problem persists. I'd also recommend following @YuviGr's advice.

Comment: @Vatsal Manot I've creat a new project but Xcode is keep freezing.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6.1.1 is pretty buggy (especially if you're using tabs) and actually we can only hope for Apple to release a bugfix version soon. But one thing that often helps is deleting the user data (UI state):

- Close Xcode.
- In your `MyProject.xcodeproj` or `MyProject.xcworkspace` directory, delete the `xcuserdata` directory.

  - In Finder, you'll need to right-click on the project or workspace directory and select "Show Package Contents".
- Open Xcode again.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my Xcode still freezes. Is it possible that this is the problem of my mac?

Comment: In theory, yes, it's possible that the problem is with your Mac. But it's unlikely. If you can reliable reproduce this issue then it's almost certain the issue is with Xcode. You can try using the Xcode 6.2 beta or an older version like 6.0.x instead.